# Django Корзина в Cookie

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, cookie, сессия

Всем привет подскажите как лучше поступить , у меня есть корзина , но когда я не зарегистрирован при добавлении товара в корзину выскакивает ошибка, подскажите как мне лучше сделать чтоб если юзер не залогиненый то создать его корзину в куках и заказ сохранить в бд с пометкой для анонима.

models.py

```
class Cart(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Корзина'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Корзина'
        unique_together = ('user', 'session_key',)
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, blank=True, null=True, related_name='cart',on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    owner = models.ForeignKey('Customer',null=True, verbose_name='Владелец',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    products = models.ManyToManyField(CartProduct,blank=True,related_name='related_cart')
    total_products = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=0)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,default=0, decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Общая сумма')
    in_order= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    for_anonymoys_user= models.BooleanField(default=False)
    session_key = models.CharField(max_length=40,null=True,blank=True)

    
        
    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)


class CartProduct(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Продукт для корзины'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Продукты для корзины'

    user  = models.ForeignKey('Customer',verbose_name='Покупатель', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    cart = models.ForeignKey('Cart',verbose_name='Корзина',on_delete=models.CASCADE,related_name='related_products')
    # #########################################&&&&&&&&&&?????????????????????????????
    product= models.ForeignKey(Product,verbose_name='Товар',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    qty = models.PositiveIntegerField(default=1)
    final_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10,decimal_places=2,verbose_name='Общая сумма')
    
    def __str__(self):
        return "Продукт: {} (для корзины)".format(self.product.title)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.final_price = self.qty * self.product.price
        super().save(*args, **kwargs)


class Customer(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Покупатель'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Покупатели'

    user = models.ForeignKey(User, verbose_name='Пользователь', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Номер телефона')
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Адрес', null=True, blank=True)
    orders = models.ManyToManyField('Order', verbose_name='Заказы покупателя', related_name='related_order')

    def __str__(self):
        return "Покупатель: {} {}".format(self.user.first_name, self.user.last_name)


class Order(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Заказ'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Заказы'

    STATUS_NEW ='new'
    STATUS_IN_PROGRESS='in_progress'
    STATUS_READY= 'is_ready'
    STATUS_COMPLETED= 'completed'
    STATUS_DEACTIVE='deactive'

    BUYING_TYPE_SELF= 'self'
    BUYING_TYPE_DELIVERY = 'delivery'

    STATUS_CHOICES= (
        (STATUS_NEW,'Новый заказ'),
        (STATUS_IN_PROGRESS,'Заказ в обработке'),
        (STATUS_READY,'Заказ готов'),
        (STATUS_COMPLETED,'Заказ выполнен'),
        (STATUS_DEACTIVE,'Заказ Отменен')
    )

    BUYING_TYPE_CHOICES=(
        (BUYING_TYPE_SELF,'Самовывоз'),
        (BUYING_TYPE_DELIVERY,'Доставка')
        )


    customer = models.ForeignKey(Customer, verbose_name='Покупатель', related_name='related_orders', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Фамилия')
    phone = models.CharField(max_length=20, verbose_name='Телефон')
    cart = models.ForeignKey(Cart, verbose_name='Корзина', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True, blank=True)
    adress = models.CharField(max_length=1024, verbose_name='Адрес', null=True, blank=True)
    otdel = models.CharField(max_length=20,verbose_name='Отделение', null=True, blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Статус заказ',
        choices=STATUS_CHOICES,
        default=STATUS_NEW
    )
    buying_type = models.CharField(
        max_length=100,
        verbose_name='Тип заказа',
        choices=BUYING_TYPE_CHOICES,
        default=BUYING_TYPE_SELF
    )
    comment = models.TextField(verbose_name='Комментарий к заказу', null=True, blank=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, verbose_name='Дата создания заказа')
    order_date = models.DateField(verbose_name='Дата получения заказа', default=timezone.now)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.id)

class Rewiews(models.Model):

    name= models.CharField(max_length=255, verbose_name='Имя')
    text= models.TextField('Сообщение',max_length=500)
    parent= models.ForeignKey(
        'self',verbose_name='Родитель',on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True,null=True
    )
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,verbose_name='Продукт',on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    data = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True,db_index=True,verbose_name='Добавлено')

    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.name}-{self.product}"

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='Отзыв'
        verbose_name_plural='Отзывы'
```

cartmixins.py

```
class CartMixin(View):
    def dispatch(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            customer = Customer.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
            if not customer:
                customer= Customer.objects.create(
                    user=request.user
                )
            cart = Cart.objects.filter(owner=customer,in_order=False).first()
            if not cart:
                cart= Cart.objects.create(owner=customer)
        else:
            cart= Cart.objects.filter(for_anonymoys_user=True).first()
            if not cart:
                cart= Cart.objects.create(for_anonymoys_user=True)
        self.cart=cart
        self.cart.save()
        return super().dispatch(request,*args,**kwargs)
```

views.py

```
class AddToCartView(CartMixin,View):
    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        product_slug= kwargs.get('slug')
        product= Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)

        if request.user.is_authenticated:
            cart_product,created=CartProduct.objects.get_or_create(
                user=self.cart.owner,cart=self.cart,product=product
            )
            if created:
                self.cart.products.add(cart_product)
            recalc_cart(self.cart)
            messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,'Товар добавлен в корзину')
            return redirect(product.get_absolute_url())
        else:
            # print(request.session['cartanon'])
            cart, created = Cart.objects.get_or_create(
            session_key = request.session.session_key,
            defaults = {'user': None}
             )
            return redirect(product.get_absolute_url())
            # except:
            #     new_cart = Cart()
                # new_cart.save()
                # request.session["cart_id"] = new_cart.id
                # new_cart.products.add(product)
                # new_cart.save()
                # return HttpResponse("<h1>okkk!</h1>") 

class DeleteFomCartView(CartMixin,View):

    def get(self,request,*args,**kwargs):

        product_slug=kwargs.get('slug')
        product= Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product=CartProduct.objects.get(
            user=self.cart.owner,cart=self.cart,product=product
        )
        self.cart.products.remove(cart_product)
        cart_product.delete()
        recalc_cart(self.cart)
        messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,'Товар Удален')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')


class ChangeQTYView(CartMixin,View):
    def post(self,request,*args,**kwargs):
        
        product_slug= kwargs.get('slug')
        product= Product.objects.get(slug=product_slug)
        cart_product=CartProduct.objects.get(
            user=self.cart.owner,cart=self.cart,product=product
        )
        if request.POST.get('qty')=='1':
            cart_product.qty+=1
            cart_product.save()
            recalc_cart(self.cart)
        if request.POST.get('qty')=='0':
            cart_product.qty-=1
            cart_product.save()
            recalc_cart(self.cart)

        messages.add_message(request,messages.INFO,'Кол-во изменено')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/cart/')


class CartView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = Category.objects.all()
        context = {
            'cart': self.cart,
            'category': category
        }
        return render(request, 'cart.html', context)


class CheckoutView(CartMixin, View):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        category = Category.objects.all()
        form=OrderForm(request.POST or None)
        context = {
            'cart': self.cart,
            'category': category,
            'form': form
        }
        return render(request, 'checkout.html', context)

class MakeOrderView(CartMixin,View):
    
    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        form = OrderForm(request.POST or None)
        customer = Customer.objects.get(user=request.user)
        if form.is_valid():
            new_order = form.save(commit=False)
            new_order.customer = customer
            new_order.phone = form.cleaned_data['phone']

            phone=form.cleaned_data['phone']

            new_order.first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']

            name=form.cleaned_data['first_name']

            new_order.last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
            new_order.adress = form.cleaned_data['adress']

            email=form.cleaned_data['adress']


            new_order.otdel = form.cleaned_data['otdel']
            new_order.buying_type = form.cleaned_data['buying_type']
            new_order.order_date = form.cleaned_data['order_date']
            new_order.comment = form.cleaned_data['comment']

            comment=form.cleaned_data['comment']

            new_order.save()
            self.cart.in_order = True
            self.cart.save()
            new_order.cart = self.cart
            new_order.save()
            customer.orders.add(new_order)


            # email=form.cleaned_data['adress']
            # print(email)
            # name= form.cleaned_data['first_name']
            # body= form.cleaned_data['phone']
            send_email(email,name,phone,comment)

            messages.add_message(request, messages.INFO, 'Спасибо за заказ! Менеджер с Вами свяжется')
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/')
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/checkout/')
```

Comment: `при добавлении товара в корзину выскакивает ошибка` а какая ошибка не скажете? :) Предлагаете угадывать вашу ошибку? :D

Comment: IntegrityError at /add-to-cart/probes21/
ПОМИЛКА:  null значення в стовпці "user_id" відношення "mainapp_cartproduct" порушує not-null обмеження
DETAIL:  Помилковий рядок містить (8, 1, 322.00, 8, 6, null).    Как я понимаю мне нужно дать ид пользователю?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```py
from django.contrib.sessions.models import Session
class Order(models.Model):
    session = models.ForeignKey(Session, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, blank=True, null=True)
```

Лучше корзину сохранять в сессии.

Для аннонимных пользователей при оформлении заказа создавать юзера с username=session_id.

А если пользователь залогинится, то по session_id вы найдете заказ и привяжите его к уже существующем юзеру, а пользователя с username=session_id удалите.

Comment: Можно поподробней пожалуйста?

Comment: поподробнее только писать код ), вроде понятно расписал, пиши что конкретно непонятно

Comment: непонятно если модели корзины, кастомера и товара для корзины подвязаны к юзера а юзер это User=get_user_model() , как тогда быть в случае с анонимом даже в с сессиями, при таком подходе как вы описали все равно получаю ошибку кастомера из Mixins.py

Comment: user = User.objects.create_user('session_key', 'randomemail', 'randomemail')

Comment: IntegrityError at /add-to-cart/Tshirt/
ПОМИЛКА:  null значення в стовпці "user_id" відношення "mainapp_cartproduct" порушує not-null обмеження
DETAIL:  Помилковий рядок містить (26, 1, 32.00, 8, 5, null).

Comment: Работает только не могу задать имя пользователя как session_key,The given username must be set , подскажите как исправить и задавать имена пользователя как session_key

Comment: request.session.session_key

Comment: да, но не работало, обернул в str заработало, спасибо за помощь

Comment: поздравляю! Вы сами решили проблемму с моими наводками, старайтесь и дальше разбираться самостоятельно и только когда совсем не получается, то спрашивайте. Только так вы получите дополнительные знания и дальше будете решать более сложные задачи

Comment: большое вам спасибо!